# Python Event Scheduler that Changes Intervals

Tags: python, time, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, python-module

I want to schedule a function in python to execute every x seconds. But I should be able to easily change the interval in which it runs.

```
    def func1():
        print("hello")

    s = schedule(func1, x) # It runs every x seconds
    s.run()
    s.intervaltime(z) # x second interval changed to z seconds
```

Is it possible to do this in Python?
What Modules do I have to use

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Have you done any research?

Comment: @Dan Yes, but the scheduling modules that I found weren't very flexible and couldn't be used for this purpose.